# Java: Shuffle a Deck of 32 cards?

Tags: java, methods, shuffle

I've wrote this method on my own I want to know if there is a better way to do it?

```
public Card[] shuffle(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++){
       int x = i + (int) (Math.random() * (32 - i));
       Card temp = Deck[i];
       Deck[i] = Deck[x];
       Deck[x] = temp;
    }
    return Deck;
}
```

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(convertArrayToCollectionHere)`

Comment: Doesn't look too bad. Apart from the obvious alternative that's already been pointed out I would recommend to adopt Java naming conventions and use lower case names for methods and variable names.

Comment: @JigarJoshi I will check that out later. Since I don't know about collections yet.

Answer (score 2):

You not checking, if `( 32 - i )` ever gives any value less than `0`. The algorithm is called [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffling algorithm, which resemble very much like yours:

```
private int [] shuffleMyArray ( int [] array ) {
    int size = array.length, i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while ( size != 0 ) {
        i = ( ( int ) ( Math.random () * size-- ) );
        if ( i < 0 ) {
            i = 0;
        }
        temp = array [ size ];
        array [ size ] = array [ i ];
        array [ i ] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

The output of both the algorithms will better make you understand the difference between the two, see how `Fisher-Yates` take all indices into account, while shuffling.

OUTPUT:

```
Actual Array
0 1 2 3 4 
Your Implementation output
i: 0 x: 3
i: 1 x: 4
i: 2 x: 3
i: 3 x: 4
i: 4 x: 4
Fisher Yates implementation output
i: 4 size: 4
i: 2 size: 3
i: 1 size: 2
i: 0 size: 1
i: 0 size: 0
```

Comment: Here I found a very good site for learning such [algorithms](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/#shuffling)

Comment: Yes you are right I didn't check it. Can you explain why should I? Becuase obviously it will never be less than zero.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian: You are true, in that. I never did looked so closely in that limited time, as I was getting ready to leave for my workplace. Now since I came here, I managed to put forth the output of both the algorithms for you, just to check, how they both takes different indices for swapping. The ouput is descriptive enough to tell the difference, between which approach is more efficient.

Comment: @HaroutTatarian: If I look more closely, as I am doing it still :-), it seems your algorithm is quite efficient as Fisher Yates Algorithm. I am still testing it, will try some more thought to it. Seems like yours is a very good algorithm :-) Even your algorithm is taking every index in a very efficient way, or in some way it is similar to Fisher Yates, just in that algorithm, one is decreasing the range to select a random number from, yours is just decreasing that in other way, like first 0 to 4, then 1 to 4, then 2 to 4 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make the `deck` an argument, and the method `static`. That way it's self contained. In Java, naming conventions are to make variables and method names start with a lower case letter. Next, the shortest way I know is to shuffle the deck in place with [`Collections.shuffle(List)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) and [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like

```
public static void shuffle(Card[] deck) {
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(deck));
}
```

If you want to preserve the original `deck`, then you could copy it and `return` like

```
public static Card[] shuffle(Card[] deck) {
    List<Card> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(deck));
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    return al.toArray(new Card[deck.length]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can get a better result if you choose the item to be exchanged from the whole deck and not only from the remaining cards, like this:

```
public Card[] Shuffle(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++){
       int x = (int) (Math.random() * 32);
       Card temp = Deck[i];
       Deck[i] = Deck[x];
       Deck[x] = temp;
    }
    return Deck;
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, picking a card from full range is actually worse. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias) is a good discussion of implementation errors; using full range is a common problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Surprisingly, indeed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This may lead to a bad shuffle, meaning the random number may never select certain cards from the deck.

Comment: This shuffle could be biased. Use Fisher-Yates instead.